# Ubuntu 16.04 Software Updater: you stopped checks for updates

Tags: update-manager

[image: Message on Software Updater]

Every time I open Software Updater to check for updates, I always got a message like this (You stopped checks for updates). After that, I got message "System problem detected". And every time I reboot the system, the pop up "System problem detected" always shows up. I've tried to delete the crash file by `sudo rm /var/crash/*`, but it always comes back.

Comment: Please open a terminal and run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt full-upgrade`. If any, please [edit] and post the error message in its entirety.

Comment: I already run sudo apt-full upgrade but it shows no errors. It just says "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` first ?

Comment: yes, I did run it.

Comment: try `sudo cat /var/log/apt/term.log` or `cat /var/log/apt/history` and inspect any cause to this problem. Does `sudo dpkg --configure -a` helps?

Comment: I already inspect `/var/log/apt/term.log`, but there's only a warning about a duplicate certificate. And I did try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` before, but it doesn't help. Update from terminal seem to work. Only software updater that doesn't work.

Comment: It would seem that there's an error in `/usr/sbin/aptd`. Here's the report if I run `aptd --version`:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/aptd", line 37, in <module>
    import aptdaemon.core
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .worker import DummyWorker
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` solved the problems. There must be an error because I use both python 3.5 and 3.6. The error must happened after I reinstall some python 3.6 package. Now the software-updater is working again.
I got this from github https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/3078
. There's also `chardet` package that lost from python 3.5 installation, that cause the `package-downloader` from `update-notifier` to crash. So I run`sudo pip3 install --upgrade requests` that also install `chardet`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387799/importerror-cannot-import-name-chardet