# Ubuntu 16.04: Software updater and pip stopped working

Tags: 16.04, python, update-manager, pip

Today I upgraded the Python library `matplotlib` with the following command:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Everything looked normal during the installation process. But since then, I experience two problems. One is that `pip` doesn't work any more. Every `pip` command evokes the same error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort
```

Additionally, Ubuntu's Software Updater stopped working. It looks similar [to this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961567/ubuntu-16-04-software-updater-you-stopped-checks-for-updates), only the solution won't work, because, well, `pip` doesn't work. But I guess, the Software Updater problem will disappear, when the `pip` problem is solved.

I've tried so far the following commands from threads with similar problems to no avail

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install --reinstall aptdaemon
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip
```

And obviously no `pip` command will work, e.g.

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, what looked like [an answer that solved my problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/998674/757139), but it is rather a sledgehammer method that doesn't help in the long run. Deleting a whole directory is probably not the most elegant way:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

Afterwards pip was not installed, so I reinstalled it with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

`pip` was back and working and the problem with the Software Updater was as expected resolved as well. This "solution" works, though it removes many libraries like `matplotlib`, which have to be reinstalled afterwards. But when I reinstalled `matplotlib` 2.1.2, the same `pip` error was induced. I really can't recommend this approach.

**tl; dr:** Don't do this.

So back to square one. What resolved the problem was to reinstall `pip` and every following library with `sudo -H`, e.g.

```
sudo -H apt install --reinstall python3-pip
```

Without the `-H` flag, an installation of `matplotlib` evoked the same `pip` problem. But still I got the error message. The solution seems to be [this modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48126778/8881141) originating [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/885#issuecomment-307696027):

> I edited line #2121~2122 of this file:
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py

```
#orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
#module.__path__[:] = [_normalize_cached(p) for p in orig_path]
orig_path_t = list(orig_path)
orig_path_t.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
module.__path__[:] = [_normalize_cached(p) for p in orig_path_t]
```

This revived pip/pip3 and I was able to install modules. So far, everything is working. Let's hope, this will be the last of it.

Edit: One week later, the problem hasn't resurfaced, so I mark this as the accepted answer.

Edit 2: A `pip` update revived the problem. Seemingly, the update had overwritten the modification. It was no problem to reintroduce it again and get rid of the aberrant behaviour.

Comment: You should be able to achieve the same *without* the `sudo rm` line. NEVER remove files places by a package manager unless you really know what you are doing. Doing so often solves the immediate problem, but creates a much worse problem later when you discover your package manager is mysteriously broken.

Comment: This was fixed in https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/b005a9bb84c1903bf438d57c33938e67e8bb2b29#diff-1a61d4de4eda655d48c0de747bcf5c8eR2128 about a year ago.

And the *real* fix is to use virtualenvs instead of the iffy "sudo pip". ;)