# Software Updater is saying "You stopped the check for updates". What should I do?

Tags: updates, update-manager

Whenever I open Software Updater, I get

> You stopped the check for updates.

[image: Software Updater screenshot]

---

**Context:**
I opened Software Updater app and there were some updates pending, so I clicked on 'Install Now'. The Software Updater app looked like this after pressing 'Install now':

[image: Blank Software Updater screenshot]

I couldn't understand if the updates were installing or not. I closed the app and re-opened it. The updates were not installed. I pressed 'Install Now' again and I got the same blank screen (like the above photo). I closed the app and installed the updates using terminal (`sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`).

Now when I opened the Software Updater app, I got this:

[image: Software Updater screenshot]

I tried running `/usr/bin/update-manager` from terminal and got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 487, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
    daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
    return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 487, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
    daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
    return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 177, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    return self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.debian.apt': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1594, in on_error
    error.raise_exception()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 130, in raise_exception
    raise self.value.with_traceback(self.traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 487, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1623, in _run_transaction_helper
    daemon = get_aptdaemon(self.bus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1709, in get_aptdaemon
    return dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.debian.apt",
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    return self.ProxyObjectClass(self, bus_name, object_path,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 250, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 182, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 277, in start_service_by_name
    return (True, self.call_blocking(BUS_DAEMON_NAME, BUS_DAEMON_PATH,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
    reply_message = self.send_message_with_reply_and_block(
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1
```

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Start `synaptic` and click the **Reload** button. Tell me what happens.

Comment: @heynnema Should I type `synaptic` in terminal?

Comment: Just use the standard SUPER key method, like any other app.

Comment: @heynnema There's no app named `synaptic` in my PC

Comment: Install it then.

Comment: @heynnema Please check this question once: https://askubuntu.com/q/961567/1103140 Is there any connection between my situation and that question?

Comment: What's happening with `synaptic`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113252/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-heynnema).

Comment: same for me in a quite fresh Ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 0):

If you're connected to the internet, click `check again`.

Or, in any case,  click `OK`, and try again later.

Comment: If I click check again, it's still showing the same. If I click OK, the app closes. If I reopen the app, it's still showing the same.